# Error: Demasiados valores en Oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta en `SQL`:

```
select G300CTA from GSCF300 where G300CTA NOT IN (
            select 
                sum(G323.G303MNTD) + sum(G323.G303MNTE) as SALDO,
                G300.G300CTA AS CUENTA
            from GSCF323 G323
                inner join GSCF300 G300 on G300.G300UUID = G323.G303UUID
                where  
                G323.G303IMVI = 'P' AND  G323.G303DEL = ' ' AND G323.G303DBCR = 'D' AND TRUNC(G323.G303FEMI) = '2019/02/15'
            group by G300.G300CTA
)
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error:

> ORA-00913: demasiados valores
>   00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

La idea de la consulta es obtener las cuentas (G300CTA) que no esten en la subconsulta dentro del `NOT IN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta dentro del IN regresa dos columnas, el compilador no sabrá contra cuál columna comparar GSCF300.G300CTA. Debes quitar la columna SALDO.